# How to increase or decrease the lifetime of a session?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)
>   [How to set lifetime of session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360093/how-to-set-lifetime-of-session)

How to increase or decrease the lifetime of a session?
My requirement is session should timeout and all the session variables should be unset automatically after the prescribed time limit.
I used this code but the session did not timeout.Why?

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 60);// should timeout after 1 minute
```

Comment: You need to learn to use the search functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(isSet($_SESSION['started'])){
  if((mktime() - $_SESSION['started'] - 60*1) > 0){
    //logout, destroy session etc
  }
}else{
  $_SESSION['started'] = mktime();
}
```