# Last php session longer

Tags: php, session

For few months I make RPG to-do/habits/project management system ( game ). The problem is that length of session is pretty small.

I checked facebook login scripts, but it has 1 year expiration. So problem not here.

http://rpgtasks.igloro.info

I cant find the right spot where i should increase length.
Hosting is not mine, but i pay for host. Should i ask them?

From phpinfo here:
http://rpgtasks.igloro.info/phpinfo.html

We can see session.cache_expire set to 180. Is it php session? Should I increase it?

Thanks for help

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-cache-expire.php - `session_cache_expire(3600);` or more if you are using the default PHP session handler.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360093/how-to-set-lifetime-of-session

Comment: Should i set cache_expire on every page? or only login page. 
Also i noticed from Rakesh link that in examples it requires cache_expire before session_start or it doesn't matters?

Comment: It does matter. The function absolutely *needs* to be before `session_start()` on every single call.

Comment: you should differ between `login-token` which is a token that is stored as cookie and allows to check _if the user is logged in_ (used for the keep me logged in feature)  and the session data which also has a cookie which stores a key to the server side session storage. the session data is normal deleted after e.g. 30 min of inactivity to avoid wasted storage of unused sessions.