# how to increase session time upto seven days

Tags: php, session

hi friend i use the following code for increment session on server host side as

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
session_start();
```

but the session is expire in 1440 seconds.

i use as the following code

```
var_dump(ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
var_dump(ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
```

it returns as returns string(1) "0" string(4) "1440"

thanks and regards

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set it as constant number and input variable name? It would be easier for you to modified in the future also.
Example :

```
var SESSION_MAX_LIFE = 60*60*24*7;
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', SESSION_MAX_LIFE );
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', SESSION_MAX_LIFE );
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    session_start();
```

sorry if any syntax error cause I don't know much about PHP :).

Comment: That's not the answer to the question ;)

Comment: sorry about that, I saw the return error and gave out my opinion :). @VincentBeltman

Answer (score 0):

For set the time life in php, you can use the function session_set_cookie_params, before the

session_start. here's [a link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to documentation for the function.

use it like this :

```
<?php
  $lifetime=7200; // this is set in seconds so, 7200 is 2 hours.
  session_set_cookie_params($lifetime,'/'); //the '/' parameter is set to let the session be 
                                           //used in all files in your current directory.
  session_start();
?>
```

in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360093/how-to-set-lifetime-of-session)  is a more elaborate explanation on session lifetime and how to maintain it for hours or days.