# how to make the php session variable remain set

Tags: php, session, session-state

I have looked around on Stack Overflow and many other sites for a solution to my problem but still no solution has come and I don't even get how my problem is even possible. The question is at the bottom of the post.

Here are the contents of *login.php*:

```
include("loginFunctions.php");
include("databaseFunctions.php");

if(checkSession())
{
    header("location: adminArtist.php");
    exit();
}
```

Here are the contents of *loginFunctions.php*:

```
function checkSession()
{
$isOnLine = false;
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["online"]))
{
    $isOnLine = true;
    session_regenerate_id(true);

}
else
{
    endSession();
}
    return $isOnLine;
}
```

Here are the contents of *adminArtist.php*:

```
include("loginFunctions.php");
if(!checkSession())
{
    header("location: login.php");
    exit(); 
}
```

Here's the problem I have: When I login I get to the adminArtist page, so that means `$_SESSION["online"] = true` in both login.php and adminArtist.php. However, when I hit the submit button or press F5 or reload the page in any other way, it sends me back to login screen. This is probably because all of a sudden the `$_SESSION["online"]` has become false.

What do I have to do to keep the value as *true*?

I was not sure how much code I needed to post, but I think this should be enough to locate what I have done wrong. Otherwise I will edit and add more.

Comment: Try adding session_start(); to all the pages past the initial login page just inside the opening <?php tag

Comment: First try to use session_start on each page at top just under <?php .The other problem is may be on each page refresh your session is destroyed.So you need to made your session with some  longer time period. Please check this link that how can you do this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360093/how-to-set-lifetime-of-session

Comment: I tried on multiple locations to put the session time to 3600, both when login was made, when adminartist was loaded and in the checkSession function. neither worked. So not sure if im doing it right.

Comment: Please edit your post to contain the relevant code from _login.php_ which would set the value for `$_SESSION` and any redirect code, output linking to _adminArtist.php_, etc...

Comment: Thank you for your effort with editing and help Sam Onela, however this project is outdated and i should have deleted it a long time ago.