# PHP Session not expired with in 24 minutes of php default expiry time

Tags: php, session, xampp

I know PHP session default value is 24 minutes.
This is I ensured from the phpinfo();
But My session is not expired till I close the browser.
I am using XAMPP on Windows 7 machine.

Below is my php session values

[image]

My question is not to increase or decrease the session time.
Why it is not expired after 24 minutes.

Comment: This link might help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

Comment: You can also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360403/5297359

Comment: I know how to extend the life time of session. But here my question is why my session not expired after 24 minutes(php default values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for not losing session for my application.
When I continuously working on the application the session will be initiated again and again.

Only when the user left the application more than 24 minutes means only session is expiring.