# gc_maxlifetime not working PHP

Tags: php

I've uploaded my custom PHP website on Hostgator server. My problem is system automatically destroy session and logout after few minutes if no movement on screen.

I've tried by putting gc_maxlifetime and gc_maxlifetime in header but not working. is there any other solution? I would appreciate any ideas.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

ini_set(session.cookie_lifetime, 86400);
ini_set(session.gc_maxlifetime, 86400);

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
.
.
.  
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set lifetime of session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360093/how-to-set-lifetime-of-session)

Answer (score 2):

Set it before `session_start();` :

```
<?php 
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(session.cookie_lifetime, 86400);
ini_set(session.gc_maxlifetime, 86400);
session_start();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php