# How to logon to multiple subdomains at once

Tags: php, session, authentication, cross-domain, subdomain

I have multiple subdomains and they all use the same database with the same user table.
When I login to a.domain.com I want also to be logged in to b.domain.com, etc.

I've found multidomain-sso (https://github.com/0k/multidomain-sso) but our problem is that we can have up to 100 subdomains, and I'm afraid that the approach of mutlidomain-sso will slow the login process, because it visits every subdomain through AJAX.

How can I login to one subdomain and be logged in to the other 100 subdomains also?

Comment: you can persist your sessions in database with help of SessionHandler i wrote a full description  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514033/php-sessions-keep-timing-out/54514199#54514199

Comment: I've looked in to it, and have tried it. But every subdomain creates it's own session_id in the database. So how must the other subdomain know witch session to use, because right now it creates his own session

Comment: i was wrong! sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login is based on cookie and session data . you need to set php session id(PHPSESSID) to set in a cookie with main domain.
you can login in main domain or set your cookie to access your domain and subdomains.

```php
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
$rootDomain = '.example.com';
session_set_cookie_params(
    $currentCookieParams["lifetime"],
    $currentCookieParams["path"],
    $rootDomain,
    $currentCookieParams["secure"],
    $currentCookieParams["httponly"]
);
session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();
setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue, time() + 3600, '/', $rootDomain);
?>
```